# Is it possible to deselect random elements?

Tags: selection-tools

I know you can select random elements (verts, edges, etc.) however is it possible to *de*select elements?

I want to be able to select random elements in a certain area (which would be defined by a preexisting selection)

I tried

1. Selecting an area
2. Inverting the selection
3. Hiding the inverted selection
4. Selecting random elements
5. Unhiding

The only problem is the hidden elements are selected when they are shown again. It can sometimes be a pain to deselect these without affecting the randomly selected area.

Comment: Note: this is a good TODO, will check on adding this ability.

Comment: Added design task to see about changing behavior: https://developer.blender.org/T38087

Comment: Committed, 2.70 (or any new build) has this feature. https://developer.blender.org/rB7ae1949517a41fbc46ca452f3fa40e7079273503

Comment: @ideasman42 Thanks a bunch :) To be honest I half hoped this would happen when I asked this question ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To randomly de-select:

1. Invert the selection.
2. Select random.
3. Enable the extend option.
4. Invert the selection.

---

**Update**: Recent builds (and the upcoming 2.70 release), now have the option to de-select randomly. (See https://developer.blender.org/rB7ae1949517a41fbc46ca452f3fa40e7079273503)

Answer (score 4):

After selecting your random vertices, assign them to a vertex group.  Then unhide everything, unselect everything.  Finally, select the vertex group.

Comment: Of course! Thanks. Though it would be nice if there was a way to deselect random elements, it would be a lot faster.. (And I think it would be able to do anything that selecting could)

Comment: Here is a faster process: 1. Select the area you want to randomize 2. Invert Selection 3. Hide Selection 4. Random Selection and adjust slider so that the unselected vertices are the ones you want to designate as random 5. Unhide 6. Invert Selection. -----  Remember that when you randomly select vertices, you are also randomly leaving vertices unselected.

Answer (score 2):

**2021 update:**

while in edit mode, select what you need to reduce randomly, go to "SELECT > SELECT RANDOM" and from the widget in the lower left (see screenshot below), choose "ACTION = DESELECT"

[image]